# how to sorted a dict

Tags: python, dictionary

how can i sort the element of a dictionary:

```
with open('directory file txt','r') as f:
     for line in f:
              keys = line.strip().split('.')
              value = keys[-1]
              for key in reversed(keys[1:-1]):
                     value = {key: value}
              result[keys[0]]=value
```

now if a print keys i have this:

```
['a','b','c','d','1']
['a','f','e','d','3']
['f','b','c','d','2']
['a','b','c','d','0']
```

i can i order each by the last element and save it into the file?
so my output will be:

```
a.b.c.d.0
a.b.c.d.1
f.b.c.d.2
a.f.e.d.3
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the dictionary. You can read the lines in as a list:

```
with open('directory file txt','r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

Then sort the list directly by specifying a sorting key:

```
lines.sort(key = lambda s: int(s.rsplit('.', 1)[1]))
```

Comment: ok thanks, but if i want to order the element of a multi dictionary i can i do it?

Comment: @user1841492: Dictionaries don't have order. Lists have order.

Comment: yes sure.. but if i want to print the element of a dictionary ordered by value?

Comment: @user1841492: You can use `sorted`. It works with any collection. The syntax is `sorted(yourdict, key=...)`.